# Angular Material - passing value to radio group

Tags: angular, angular-material

Why passing the value to `mat-radio-group` doesn't work? Any of these two buttons is checked. But if I explicitly use `value="2"` in `mat-radio-group` everything works fine.

TS inside class

```
 radioValue = 2;
```

HTML

```
<mat-radio-group [value]="radioValue">
        <mat-radio-button class="mr-2" value="1">Male</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2">Female</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: use [(ngModel)], not value (or [ngModel] if you only want "one-way" binding

Comment: the above answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the data type, you're merging `string` and `number`. Change your template as follows (also use `[value]` with `mat-radio-button`):

```
<mat-radio-group [value]="radioValue">
    <mat-radio-button class="mr-2" [value]="1">Male</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="2">Female</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```